# (this) is recognised on react js callback

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, babeljs

```
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props){
        super(props);

         this.state = {
           histories: [
                {
                 "name": "Test1",
                 "date":"25/05/2017",
                 "question": "Are you happy, today?",
                 "answer":"Yes"
                }, 
                {
                 "name": "Test2",
                 "date":"25/05/2017",
                 "question": "Are you happy, today?",
                 "answer": "Yes"
                }
              ] }; 

               $.ajax({
          url: "http://localhost:xxxx/api/Surveys",
          success: (data) => {
              this.setState({surveys: data});
            },
            error: function(xhr,status,err){
              console.log('error');
            }
        });
        }

         onFormSubmit(id) {
        console.log("Started");
        fetch("http://localhost:xxxx/api/Surveys/" + id + "/submit", {
            method:'POST'
        })
        .then(function(response){
          if(response.ok) {
            console.log('success');
            //this is not defined here
             this.setState({
               histories: [
                {
                 "name": "Test3",
                 "date":"25/05/2017",
                 "question": "Are you happy, today?",
                 "answer":"Yes"
                }, 
                {
                 "name": "Test4",
                 "date":"25/05/2017",
                 "question": "Are you happy, today?",
                 "answer": "Yes"
                }
              ]
          })
          }
          else {
            console.log('error');
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error){
          console.log('catch error');
        });
      }
 render(){
    return ( 
      <div>
          <History 
           Histories={this.state.histories} />
      </div>
    );
  }
      }
```

Hi,I am new to react, I have declared histories in the constructor, I tried to set histories state in webservice when call back, this is undefined when I debug it.
this is defined in `<History Histories={this.state.histories} />`, but it is undefined inside callback, would anyone give me hand on it, please? I have searched, some people recommend using  ref, but how could ref connect with this state, please? I would appreciate if anyone give an example on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass arrow function as success callback for AJAX call inside `onFormSubmit` method to make sure that `this` inside this callback points to the component:

```
onFormSubmit(id) {
        console.log("Started");
        fetch("http://localhost:xxxx/api/Surveys/" + id + "/submit", {
            method:'POST'
        })
        .then((response) => {
             ...
        })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to set the "histories" in the onFormSubmit function. To access "this" of the component, you need to bind it to the function, i.e.

```
onFormSubmit {
.... 
}.bind(this)
```

or in the constructor

```
this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this)
```